# NLog in docker compose not giving file output

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, nlog

I'm trying to set up logging for my application using `NLog`. The app is running in a **docker service** along with other services such as a database. I'm not sure if that creates any issues, but I doubt it as I set up internal logging and that works fine. I set up `NLog` to have two targets: a console target and a file target. The internal log tells me it loaded those two targets from my config I specified. Now, the weird thing is, I get console output, but no file gets created.

## nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="logs/internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"></add>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- console log -->
    <target name="consolelog" xsi:type="Console"></target>

    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/${shortdate}-n.txt" Layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"></target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!-- log everything from application namespace to console -->
    <logger name="vote_server.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="consolelog"></logger>

    <!-- log everything from application namespace to file -->
    <logger name="vote_server.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile"></logger>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to check permissions for doing file-write?

Comment: I'm having similar problems with an asp.net core project running on alpine in a docker container. NLog is configured to log to a directory in the app directory. However, no log file appears. It does log when running on my windows dev computer.

Comment: @Domin try looking in the `app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1` directory on the docker container. I'm guessing the log output directory depends on "where" the application is currently running. Weirdly, I'm getting logs in both locations.

Comment: @lennyy Thanks for replying. Your comment made me question a couple of things, so I built a test project and everything worked. So I compared my project dependencies and I was mistakenly including the regular NLog library. It appears this disrupted the expected behavior and once removed, NLog.Web.AspNetCore was able to log correctly.

Comment: @Domin So that means I should remove the `NLog` NuGet package? Right now I've got both `NLog` and `Nlog.Web.AspNetCore` installed, I thought the `AspNetCore` one depends on the 'normal' `NLog` package.

Comment: @lennyy That's correct. For .Net Core there is only one NLog library, which is Nlog.Web.AspNetCore.